# Remapping Y and Z keys with Karabiner

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, xml, karabiner

I just want to switch the <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> keys. I've tried everything with Karabiner on High Sierra, but it just doesn't seem to work. I always get an error message along the lines of: "Karabiner Error. Error in xml. Unknown symbol: KeyCode::0x6"

Attached you can see the code that I've been trying to use, as well as the modifier keys for <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> (which I've tried every variation of in the code).

```
   <root>
      <item>
      <name>Swap Space and Tab</name>
      <identifier>private.swap_z_and_y</identifier>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::0x6, KeyCode::0x10</autogen>
      <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::0x10, KeyCode::0x6</autogen>
      strong text</item>
   </root>
```

Please help!

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

ahem … Karabiner 10.xx no longer works with MacOS (High) Sierra …

The interim app Karabiner Elements 12.10 will solve your problem ***very*** easily, but "Complex Modifications" –meaning modifier/key combinations or e.g. "if_held_down"– can locally only be added/modified by manually editing      `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`.

Here's a comprehensive guide for the interested ones: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x1C,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x1D},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x1D,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x1C}]}'
```

use this to remap without using any external lib .

you can find supporting docs :-

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html
>
> Karabiner Gui Guide Just Select Key And Swap :-
>
> https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help either. Now I get this error message:

Error in XML. 
</Users/xxxxx/Library/Application Support/Karabiner/private.xml>(1): expected <